# How does Maven parse SNAPSHOT versions from repositories

Tags: java, maven

I'm developing a server that hosts a maven repo and face the problem that Maven incorrectly resolves SNAPSHOT-versions if the snapshot is not in a specific format. After looking up the rules for versions, I understand that the qualifier can be any string, so I expect maven to be able to download dependencies with any qualifier. This doesn't match my experience however.

The repo has the following folder structure (assuming a maven project `a.b.c:a.b.c.d:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`):

```
<repo-root>
|-a
 |-b
  |-c
   |-a.b.c.d
    |-maven-metadata.xml
    |-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
     |-a.b.c.d-1.0.0-20190213.120000-1.jar
     |-maven-metadata.xml
```

If I try to resolve a.b.c.d-SNAPSHOT, this works just fine. I can see in the maven log that it looks for `a/b/c/a.b.c.d/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml` and then downloads the correct JAR-file. So far so good.

But if I change the qualifier to something else (like removing the -1 at the end), maven is unable to resolve the file! Instead of looking for

```
<repo-root>/a/b/c/a.b.c.d/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/<jar-file>
```

(which would be correct), it looks at

```
<repo-root>/a/b/c/a.b.c.d/1.0.0-20190213.120000/<jar-file>
```

which is obviously wrong. This happens with every qualifier that doesn't fit the format

```
\d\.\d\.\d-\d{8}.\d{6}-\d+
```

Why can't Maven resolve such qualifiers? Is the format specified somewhere or is this just a maven bug?

Comment: Could you please clarify something for me: Are you developing your own Maven Repository or do you include a given Maven Repository (like Nexus, Artifactory or the standard local repository) into a server? What do you mean by "removing -1 at the end"? Are you requesting a timestamp through maven or do you change the file in the directory?

Comment: I am developing my own repository. By "removing the -1 at the end" I mean that I change the format of the qualifier in the filename. I name the files myself (the JAR-files generated in a maven build have other qualifiers anyway)

Comment: First why are trying to develop something and you mentioned that something is wrongly solved ? the trailing `-1` is used to distinguish artifacts which are deployed within the same timestamp range cause the timestamp has a resolution of a second. So if you deploy two artifacts within the same second you will get `-1` for the first one and `-2` for the second. Furthermore I don't understand your issue with resolution

Answer (score 2):

In general, Maven versions can be any String (like `1.2.3-RELEASE`, `1-1456` or `dontknow`). Versions ending in `-SNAPSHOT` have the special meaning that they are resolved against the latest build version.

The different versions for one specific SNAPSHOT (like `1.0-SNAPSHOT`) are distinguished by the timestamps you mentioned in your question. I do not know whether this format is really a "Maven standard", but I guess so because it is the same in all common repository managers and you experienced problems in not using it. I would strongly advise against using different kinds of timestamps even if you make it work because the expectation of every Maven plugin is that timestamped SNAPSHOT versions have a defined and given format (whether this is "official" or not).

By the way: I would be very interested to hear why you develop your own Maven repository.

Comment: We are actually working on a change for Package Drone (https://github.com/eclipse/packagedrone) that caused the issue for us. So not really "developing our own Maven repository", but it didn't add anything to the question, so I cheated a bit with the explanation there.